# Javascript hide table colum without having an ID

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, html-table

I don't have the td ID, I have the table ID but the TD is within another table

e.g.

```
<table id="myid">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
```

I want to hide the 4th td only.

The formatting result doesn't matter, I just need to remove the 4th column fully.

Tried using `ElementByTagName` but it doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: your html seems to be invalid..

Comment: Why do you use jquery tag since you don't used it ?

Comment: Don't forget the "s" in "ElementsByTagName"

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$('#myid tr td').eq(3).hide();
```

Even you can try like

```
$('#myid tr td:eq(3)').hide();
```

Consider that it will count the `td` from `0`,so it will hide the `Fourth` td.

Comment: See the tags that he was added to this question

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
$('#myid table tr td:eq(1)').hide();
```